# How to use a PHP variable in Javascript using Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I use this error code when this information is not found while I echo the JS variable, but it doesn't work in PHP function

```
$(document).click(function() {
        $('#more').empty();
        $('#detail-more').empty();

        $.get('/inbox', function(date) {
            $.each(date, function(app, subcatObj) {
                var time = timeAgo(subcatObj.created_at);
                if (subcatObj.id == id) {
                    var id =subcatObj.id;
                    $('#detail-more').html(`<div class="peers peer-greed">` +
                        `<div class="peer mR-20"><img class="bdrs-50p w-3r h-3r" alt="" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/11.jpg"></div>` +
                        `<div class="peer"><small>${time}</small>` +
                        `<h5 class="c-grey-900 mB-5"></h5><span>Then:<?php app\User::find(${id})->name; ?> </span></div>` +
                        `</div>` +
                        `<div class="peer"><a href="" class="btn btn-danger bdrs-50p p-15 lh-0"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></a></div>`);
                    $('#more').html(`<h4> ${subcatObj.title} </h4><p> ${subcatObj.text}</p>`);
                }

            });
        });
    });
```

> error:"Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' (this will throw an
> Error in a future version of PHP) (View:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\tasvirevarzesh\resources\views\dashboard\email\index.blade.php)"

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: You can't use PHP inside JavaScript. One is server-side, the other one is client-side. I suggest you to read a tutorial on this topic!

Comment: First learn php better then ask questions. By the way it's not a good practice but you can use php code inside JS (but not dynamically) with this code will compile at server side before send code to browser. Better use Ajax texnology.

Comment: @Ermenegildo `"You can't use PHP inside JavaScript"` - yes, you can: `var a = "<?= $b; ?>";`

Comment: @user7290573 that's not **using** PHP inside JavaScript, that's just printing a PHP variable. We could argue on the various definition of `using PHP`, but this isn't the place. Still, the point is that he can't call PHP function using JavaScript variable, unless he calls such function through an API, which will be the definition of "using a WebService", and not "using PHP from JavaScript". Hope this clear the point.. :)

Comment: @Ermenegildo yes, clears up the point - wasn't 100% sure that's what you meant. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

1. if you write in others js files you should use input type="hidden"
   in blade to get value and then handle it.
2. You can use

   in blade and use {{ }} to coding something here